# sql qUERY for displaying data using Between operator

Tags: mysql

I want to display data from two tables on web Page, but this query not taking the value of first textbox i.e Date1

```
SELECT Distinct Student.stu_name,
       Attendanc.Stu_id, 
       Attendanc.Date,
       Attendanc.time,
       Attendanc.Status
  FROM Attendanc,
       Student
 WHERE Attendanc.Stu_id = Student.Stu_id 
   AND Student.Email='"+add_email+"' 
   AND Attendanc.Date BETWEEN '" + Date1 + "' AND '"+Date2+"'"
```

Comment: If you are learning SQL, you should learn to avoid commas in the `from` clause (use explicit `join` syntax) and how to use table aliases.

Comment: Commas are perfectly allowable (they are just a synonym for join) providing you structure the WHERE clause properly everything will work. Table aliases can save time typing but lead to confusion in larger statements. Now, on the topic, could it simply be because you have spaces in + Date1 + that you do not have in +Date2+ ?

Comment: What Language are tou working in? What you wrote is not pure SQL. Please see what the actual query really is